# Can a pointer of a derived class be type cast to the pointer of its base class?

Tags: c++

The pointer of derived class returned by new can be type cast to the pointer of its base class.

Is this true or false?

I know dynamic_cast can be used to cast downside. Generally, how to cast a pointer of derived class to a pointer of its base class?

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Is "casted" even a word? I thought the past participle (or whatever) of "cast" is "cast".

Comment: .. while we are at it, 'cast' suffices; 'type cast' (with or without the space) is treated as a sign of ignorance by some pedants. YMMV. ;)

Comment: @dirkgently: <sarcasm> Perhaps he thought he could cast other things like functions, members, templates, you never know. </sarcasm>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.  Conversion from a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to a base class is implicit.  Thus, the following is perfectly fine:

```
struct B { };
struct D : B { };

D* my_d_ptr = new D;
B* my_d_ptr_as_a_b_ptr = my_d_ptr;
```

Comment: +1: however for clarity for the beginners out there, I'm just pointing out that the converse isn't true, and upcasts are inherently unsafe i.e. "B* b = new D();" is safe, but "D* d = new B()" is not. Thanks.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Upcasts are very safe. Downcasts require `dynamic_cast`. (D -> B = upcast; B -> D = downcast)

Comment: @Binary Worrier:  True, but the OP seems already to know that ("I know dynamic_cast can be used to cast downside").

Comment: I seem to have a different definition of "upcast" and "downcast" from everyone else :) Apologies for any confusion folks.

Comment: If you consider the inheritance tree to be "upside down," with base classes at the top and derived classes underneath, "up" and "down" make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 6):

Casting a pointer to a derived to a pointer to base should be implicit.  This is the whole point of polymorphism:  An instance of a derived class should always be safely usable as an instance of the base class.  Therefore, no explicit cast is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

That's true if derived class inherits 'publicly' and 'non-virtually' from base:

You can't convert `Derived*` to `Base*` neither implicitly nor using static_cast/dynamic_cast (C-cast will do the job, but you should think twice before use this hack!);

```
class Base { };

class Derived : protected Base { };

int main()
{
   Base* b = new Derived(); // compile error
}
```

Also don't work if base class is ambiguous:

```
class Base { };

class Derived1 : public Base { };
class Derived2 : public Base { };

class MostDerived : public Derived1, Derived2 { };

int main()
{
   Base* b = new MostDerived(); // won't work (but you could hint compiler
                                // which path to use for finding Base
}
```

Edit: added code samples, added ambiguous use case, removed virtual inheritance example.

Comment: This answer seems confused.  Do you mean you can't convert if the inheritance is private or virtual?

Comment: I think you mean "virtually" because your example is "non-virtually" and fails. MSDN: "when the specified base class is accessible and the conversion is unambiguous"

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear becuse it mixes up several different things.

On the one hand, a pointer to derived class *can* be converted to a pointer to a base class (assuming the base is accessible). This is a natural conversion and there's no need for any cast to do it.

On the other hand, you mention `dynamic_cast` and its ability to to perform *downcasts*. But downcasts are casts in the opposite direction: from a pointer to a base class to a pointer to derived class. Downcasts can be performed by both `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` depending on what you need and what amount of run-time checking you require.

... And at the same time you ar talking about casting the result of `new`, which, of course, can only be upcasted, but not downcasted.

So, what is it you are asking about? Upcasts or downcasts?