# How to pass a Class as Parameter

Tags: c++, class, function, types, parameters

**In C++ is there a way to pass a type (e.g. a class) as parameter to a function?**

Explanation why I need this: There is a abstract `data` class and a `manager` class. The `manager` class contains a list (or in this case a map) of objects of derived classes of `data`. I use `unique_ptr` for this as mentioned in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877993/c-create-array-of-objects-from-different-classes).

```
class Data{}; // abstract

class Manager
{
    map<string, unique_ptr<Data>> List;
};
```

Now imagine I want to add a new `data` storage to the manager.

```
class Position : public Data
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}
```

How could I tell the manager to create a object of that type and refer an `unique_ptr` to it?

```
Manager manager;
manager.Add("position data", Position);
```

In this case I would need to pass the class `Position` to the `add` function of the manager class since I don't want to have to first create an instance and then send it to the manager.

**And then, how could I add the object of that class to the `List`?**

I am not sure if there is a way of doing that in C++. If that can't be done easily I would really like to see a workaround. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried using templates?

Comment: No I haven't since I am not familiar with using templates. But I have an open mind about using them and learning more about them.

Comment: I think that the answers below offer good solution with templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use templates. In each type deriving from `Data` you will have to define a 'creator' function, which have the following prototype: `Derived* create()`. It will be called internally (you can also return a `unique_ptr`, but that would requires more memory).

Ex:

```
struct Position: public Data
{
    // ...
    static Position* create()
    {
        return new Position();
    }
};
```

The `Add` method will be:

```
template<typename D>
void Add(String str)
{
    List.insert(std::make_pair(str, std::unique_ptr<Data>(D::create())));
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
Manager manager;
manager.Add<Position>("position data");
```

**EDIT**

You can also get rid of the `create` functions, by using this `Add` method:

```
template<typename D>
void Add(String str)
{
    List.insert(std::make_pair(str, std::unique_ptr<Data>(new D())));
}
```

Advantage: less code in data structure code.

Inconvenient: data structures have less control on how they're built.

Comment: That is a nice solution, too. But is there a way of getting rid of that `create` function? (Maybe move it to the base class somehow?)

Comment: Yes, you can directly use `new D()`. Less control from the structure, but more easy to implement. See edit.

Comment: Looks nice, but there is a compiler error. `Binary Operator '=': There was no operator found which accepts an operand of type 'Position *'.`

Comment: Yes that was code only to show what you should do 'self-documenting code). Editing this.

Comment: Thanks that works now. (By the way you missed one `)` in both lines.)

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this:

```
class Manager
{
 public:
  template <typename T>
  void addData(const std::string& title)
  {
    List.insert(std::make_pair(title, std::unique_ptr<Data>(new T));
  }
 private:   
  map<string, unique_ptr<Data>> List;
};
```

then

```
Manager manager;
manager.addData<Position>("position data");
```

Comment: This is nice. It there any way to restrict `typename T` to be derived from `Data`?

Comment: @sharethis well, if `T` wasn't derived from `Data`, `std::unique_ptr<Data>(new T)` would give compilation problems, unless there was a conversion from `T` to `Data`.

Comment: @sharethis if you really want to make sure, and you have C++11 support, you can use [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) together with [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert). Boost provides c++03 alternatives.

Comment: Oh, could you please provide an short example of your last idea?

Comment: @sharethis something like `static_assert(std::is_base_of<Data, T>::value, "T is not derived from Data");` but actually, I can't think of a situation where the code above would compile unless `T` is a base of `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `unique_ptr` means committing to working with dynamically allocated objects.  (Not quite true: you could supply a custom deleter that doesn't call `delete`, but that becomes part of the type; this means you would be committing to working with *non*-dynamically allocated objects.)

```
void Manager::Add(String title, unique_ptr<Data> d) {
    List[title] = d;
}
```

Call it as:

```
Manager manager;
unique_ptr<Data> pos(new Position);
// Set it up
manager.Add("position data", pos);
```

Note: If you want to be able to *do* anything with your data objects, you probably want to declare at least one virtual function inside `class Data`.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe `unique_ptr` isn't the right option to go for me. Because I want to provide a `manager.Get(string Name);` returning a pointer to that data object. What do you think?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot that `List` is actually a `map` :-P  I've edited the `Add()` implementation to fix that.  `unique_ptr` behaves just like a pointer, so you can still write `unique_ptr<Data> Manager::Get(String title) { return List[title]; }`, exactly as you would for a plain pointer.  All `unique_ptr` does is make sure that dynamically allocated pointees are cleaned up automatically.

Comment: So there wouldn't be a problem since there were two pointers then? One in the list of the manager and one returned by the get function. That doesn't sound like a *unique* pointer.

Comment: Ah. If you want to let the caller of `Get()` have access to the object without claiming ownership of it, I would suggest using a reference instead: `Data& Manager::Get(String title) { return *List[title]; }`.  You could alternatively use a plain pointer (this can be obtained by calling `get()` on a `unique_ptr`).

Answer (score 0):

Define the function as following:

```
void Manager::Add(String title,Position pos){ /*snip*/ }
```

Then you can use the function as following:

```
Manager manager;
Position posData;
//setup the posData
manager.Add("position data",posData);
```

Comment: I can't do that. Since the manager must be able to store all types derived from `data` what I need is an generalized solution. Moreover I don't want to create an instance in my main function.

Comment: You could pass temporary `Position` class that you insert into the map.

Comment: I could but if there is a way of not doing that I would prefer that. Nevertheless, the manager must be able to add every possible object of a derived class of data, not just Position.

Comment: Then `Position` could be just changed to `Data`. But it seems like you will find the answer you like from the other answers.